# jCarousel -help with new skin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-frameworks

I'm creating a new theme for the jCarousel component that I'll be
using for my web site and the dimension for this component will be:
width:485px , height:161px including the two arrows and what i want is
to have 3 items per cycle each having the a dimension of 140X100
(width X height) with 5px margin, and 3/4 of the skin is done but I'm
having a hard time with css.

P.S: Please visit this page to see the component  live
http://www.amfexglobal.com/test/static_auto.html
and if you are interested in the files download from here
http://www.mediafire.com/?ejlmmxxzdid

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Question require a question mark. Where is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps explain the problem you're having?

The way I see it (from looking at your sample), you're all right except the first and last elements are either over- or under- margined, depending on where they fall.

You can fight this two ways:

- Split up your margin, so that instead of margin: 0 5px 0 0 you're using 0px 3px 0px 2px. With an odd number, though, that's a tiny bit unbalanced.
- Better, I think is to set padding on your containing element to padding-left: 5px. That gives you a 5px "head-start", and then the right margin on each of your elements takes care of the last.

Good luck!